# Simple Injector - register IEnumerable of abstract class implementations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector and would like to see if it is possible to register/resolve a collection of classes that inherit an abstract class.

The scenario is as follows:
I have the following abstract/concrete classes:

```
public abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public abstract string MakeSound();
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string MakeSound()
        {
            return "woof";
        }
    }

    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override string MakeSound()
        {
            return "meow";
        }
    }

    public class Pig : Animal
    {
        public override string MakeSound()
        {
            return "oink";
        }
    }
```

Additionally, I have a class which should receive an `IEnumerable<Animal>` and call the `MakeSound` function for each animal, like this:

```
public class Zoo
    {
        private IEnumerable<Animal> _animals;
        public Zoo(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
        {
            _animals = animals;
        }

        public void MakeZooNoise()
        {
            foreach (var animal in _animals)
            {
                animal.MakeSound();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to build up the `IEnumerable<Animal>` collection preferably using upon Container initialization and let it be handled via Simple Injector since there are other registrations used in this child classes as well (not in this case but in the real example).

Note: if there are ideas of alternative approaches, those are welcome too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
container.RegisterCollection<Animal>(new[] {
    typeof(Cat), 
    typeof(Dog), 
    typeof(Pig)
});

// or using Auto-Registration
container.RegisterCollection<Animal>(new [] {
    typeof(Animal).Assembly
});
```

Comment: Just for my edification - that seems brittle in that the registration needs to be updated each time a new derived class is added. Could it be done in a way that doesn't require such updates?

Comment: From my understanding using a new to initialize objects defeats the purpose of using an IoC container. Wouldn't a better approach be to inherit animal interface as IDog, ICat and IPig interfaces and use them to register containers? @Steven

Comment: @AliKareemRaja newing instances by hand is not a problem as long as this happens inside the Composition Root and as long as this doesn't hurt maintainability. Further more, the only new statements in these examples are the creation of the surrounding Type and Assembly arrays, not the creation of application components.

Comment: @AliKareemRaja about your second question, there's no way for me to answer that, since it depends upon context. Such context is missing from the initial question. Whether to register a collection or unique registrations depends on the context. Feel free to post a new question on Stackoverflow about this.